# How to perform a DCT in R on a vector with NA values

Tags: r, na, dct

I'm trying to perform a Discrete Cosinus Transform on a couple of vectors. The vectors represent data evenly spaced in time. Some of the values might be NA, meaning that nothing was measured in that time period. How do I perform the DCT so it ignores the NA value or how do I generate a nice value for it.

The code I use is simply:

```
dtt::dct(myVector)
```

```
myVector =
 [1]  0  5  2  0  2  0  8  0  2  3  3  3  0  1  3  1  0  3  2  1  3  0  0  0  2  2  2  3  2
[30]  2  2  1  1  0  0  3  1  2  0  2  1  1  1  2  0  1  1  0  4  3  2  4  1  0  2  3  1  0
[59]  0  0  0  1  3 NA  1  0  1  4  3  0  2  2  0  2  3  1  1  1  0  0  3  2  1  1  2  4  2
[88]  0  2  3  4  3  0  0  1  1  2  1
```

```
output=
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[30] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[59] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[88] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

(batman)

Comment: why not remove the NAs?   Consider, A <- c(1,2,NA,3) which has one NA which can be removed with A <- A[!is.na(A)]

Comment: because the time of the measurement is an important feature of the data. Every number represents a measurement in one minute

Comment: Could you replace the NA's, as the average of the data around them, this could minimise the negative effects? for example choose a interval like closest 6 or something to compute the means?

Comment: Conversely, there seems to be a lot of information about a similar problem to yours [here](https://scicomp.stackexchang)